# Possible to copy data from row from one sheet to another?

Tags: sql, google-sheets

I would like to take data from one google sheet and use it to fill in the values of another spreadsheet. For example, I have a spreadsheet that contains emails and names. I have another that also contains emails and names but some of the emails are missing. I would like to take the emails from one sheet and insert it into another where the names match. Is it possible to do via sql query?

ie.
Sheet 1

Name Email

John Doe johndoe@gmail.com

Jane Doe

Sheet2

Name Email

John Doe johndoe@gmail.com

Jane Doe janedoe@gmail.com

I would like to copy data from sheet2 to sheet1 where the names are equal on google sheets

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `vlookup()` function to achieve what you want

documentation: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en

example spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PBUHzFXNfj8YH4tzbqdsd93038RMRd6YCiwd1yHhZMs/edit?usp=sharing